# Quadratic equation $(\ell-m)x^2-5(\ell+m)x-2(\ell -m) =0 $

Tags: quadratics

If $\ell$, m, n are real,$\ell\ne m$, then the roots by the equation :$(\ell-m)x^2-5(\ell+m)x-2(\ell -m)=0$
are

(A)Real and equal

(B) Complex

(C)Real and Unequal

(D) None of these

My approach is as follow
The discriminant $T = 25{\left( {\ell  + m} \right)^2} + 8{\left( {\ell  - m} \right)^2}$

$T = 33{\ell ^2} + 33{m^2} + 34\ell m$

$T = 33{\left( {\ell  + m} \right)^2} - 32\ell m$

not able to approach from here

Comment: Can I use $A.M. \ge G.M.$

Comment: Why do you want to use anything more? $T>0$, so you are done. Actually, one can argue that (B) is also correct, since real numbers $a$ are also complex numbers $a+0\cdot i$.

Comment: You mention $n$, is it supposed to appear in the equation somewhere?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, but if we have to pick the best option out of $4$, the answer would be $C$, right?

Comment: @aarbee It depends on the exact formulation. We should read the  homework in the "original" version. It might not be in English. "Unequal" sounds a bit strange, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first $T$ i.e. $25{\left( {\ell  + m} \right)^2} + 8{\left( {\ell  - m} \right)^2}$ is always positive. So, the roots are real and unequal.